# How to show in link Google's universal navigation in multi-language?

Tags: google-app-engine, navigation, google-apps-marketplace

As you see below, I set multi-language in Google's universal navigation for my app, but it does not work! it is always displayed in Japanese.

```
<Extension id="navlink" type="link">
  <Name>テスト</Name>
  <Name language="en">Test</Name>
  <Url>https://test.appspot.com/domain/${DOMAIN_NAME}</Url>
  <Scope ref="calendarAPI"/>
</Extension>
```

Could you show me any idea?

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue with Google Apps Marketplace. We are hoping to address this next year.